# Change audio device per application through python

Tags: python, audio, audio-device

When I want to stream some games I need to change my output devices. What I want to be able to do is, set for example my spotify output to output Cable A, my game audio to Cable B and my windows sound to cable C, all within a script. And when I stop streaming I want to run a script that changes all my applications output devices back to the regular output device. Changing the output devices for the applications will always be the same applications and the same output devices. However I simply don't know if there's some sort of library that I could use or if there already exists this kind of software. Thanks!

Comment: This is already handled by Windows, so probably you can start from C# and then look for a way to implement that  in Python

Comment: @pierpy If it is way easier to code in C#, I'm happy to do so. Is there a library for C# or how do you start?